# Resolving an ambiguous type variable

Tags: haskell, parametric-polymorphism

I have these two functions:

```
load :: Asset a => Reference -> IO (Maybe  a)
send :: Asset a => a -> IO ()
```

The Asset class look like this:

```
class (Typeable a,ToJSON a, FromJSON a) => Asset a where
  ref :: a -> Reference
  ...
```

The first reads an asset from disk, and the second transmits a JSON representation to a WebSocket.  In isolation they work fine, but when I combine them the compiler cannot deduce what concrete type `a` should be. (`Could not deduce (Asset a0) arising from a use of 'load'`)

This makes sense, I have not given a concrete type and both `load` and `send` are polymorphic.  Somehow the compiler has to decide which version of `send` (and by extension what version of `toJSON`) to use.

I can determine at run time what the concrete type of `a` is.  This information is actually encoded both in the data on the disk and the `Reference` type, but I do not know for sure at compile time as the type checker is being run.

Is there a way to pass the correct type at run time an still keep the type checker happy?

---

**Additional Information**

The definition of Reference

```
data Reference = Ref {
    assetType:: String
  , assetIndex :: Int
  } deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Generic)
```

References are derived by parsing a request from a WebSocket as follows where Parser comes from the Parsec library.

```
reference :: Parser Reference
reference = do 
  t <-    string "User" 
       <|> string "Port" 
       <|> string "Model"
       <|> ...
  char '-'
  i <- int
  return Ref {assetType = t, assetIndex =i}
```

If I added a type parameter to `Reference` I simply push my problem back into the parser.  I still need to turn a string that I do not know at compile time into a type to make this work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't make a function that turns string data into values of different types depending on what is in the string. That's simply impossible. You need to rearrange things so that your return-type doesn't depend on the string contents.

Your type for `load`, `Asset a => Reference -> IO (Maybe  a)` says "pick any `a` (where `Asset a`) you like and give me a `Reference`, and I'll give you back an `IO` action that produces `Maybe a`". The caller picks the type they expect to be loaded by the reference; the contents of the file do not influence which type is loaded. But you don't want it to be chosen by the caller, you want it to be chosen by what's stored on disk, so the type signature simply doesn't express the operation you actually want. That's your real problem; the ambiguous type variable when combining `load` and `send` would be easily resolved (with a type signature or `TypeApplications`) if `load` and `send` were individually correct and combining them was the only problem.

Basically you can't just have `load` return a polymorphic type, because if it does then the caller gets to (must) decide what type it returns. There's two ways to avoid this that are more-or-less equivalent: return an existential wrapper, or use rank 2 types and add a polymorphic handler function (continuation) as a parameter.

Using an existential wrapper (requires `GADTs` extension), it looks something like this:

```
data SomeAsset
  where Some :: Asset a => a -> SomeAsset

load :: Reference -> IO (Maybe SomeAsset)
```

Notice `load` is no longer polymorphic. You get a `SomeAsset` that (as far as the type checker is concerned) could contain any type that has an `Asset` instance. `load` can internally use whatever logic it wants split into multiple branches and come up with values of different types of asset on different branches; provided each branch ends with wrapping up the asset value with the `SomeAsset` constructor all of the branches will return the same type.

To `send` it, you would use something like (ignoring that I'm not handling `Nothing`):

```
loadAndSend :: Reference -> IO ()
loadAndSend ref
  = do Just someAsset <- load ref
       case someAsset
         of SomeAsset asset -> send asset
```

The `SomeAsset` wrapper guarantees that `Asset` holds for its wrapped value, so you can unwrap them and call any `Asset`-polymorphic function on the result. However you can never do anything with the value that depends on the specific type in any other way<sup>1</sup>, which is why you have to keep it wrapped up and `case` match on it all the time; if the `case` expression results in a type that depends on the contained type (such as `case someAsset of SomeAsset a -> a`) the compiler will not accept your code.

The other way is to instead use `RankNTypes` and give `load` a type like this:

```
load :: (forall a. Asset a => a -> r) -> Reference -> IO (Maybe r)
```

Here `load` doesn't return a value representing the loaded asset at all. What it does instead is take a polymorphic function as an argument; the function works on any `Asset` and returns a type `r` (that was chosen by `load`'s caller), so again `load` can internally branch however it wants and construct differently-typed assets in the different branches. The different asset types can all be passed to the handler, so the handler can be called in every branch.

My preference is often to use the `SomeAsset` approach, but then to also use `RankNTypes` and define a helper function like:

```
withSomeAsset :: (forall a. Asset a => a -> r) -> (SomeAsset -> r)
withSomeAsset f (SomeAsset a) = f a
```

This avoids having to restructure your code into continuation passing style, but takes away the heave `case` syntax everywhere you need to use a `SomeAsset`:

```
loadAndSend :: Reference -> IO ()
loadAndSend ref
  = do Just asset <- load ref
       withSomeAsset send asset
```

Or even add:

```
sendSome = withSomeAsset send
```

---

Daniel Wagner suggested adding the type parameter to `Reference`, which the OP objected to by stating that simply moves the same problem to when the references are constructed. If the references contain data representing which type of asset they refer to, then I would *strongly* recommend taking Daniel's advice, and using the concepts described in this answer to address that problem at the reference-constructing level. `Reference` having a type parameter prevents mixing up references to the wrong types of assets where you do know the type.

And if you do significant processing with references and assets of the same type, then having the type parameter in your workhorse code can catch easy mistakes mixing them up *even if* you usually existential the type away at the outer levels of code.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically your `Asset` implies `Typeable`, so you can test it for specific types and then return those.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, make `Reference` store the type.

```
data Reference a where
    UserRef :: Int -> Reference User
    PortRef :: Int -> Reference Port
    ModelRef :: Int -> Reference Model

load :: Asset a => Reference a -> IO (Maybe a)
send :: Asset a => a -> IO ()
```

If necessary, you can still recover the strong points of your original `Reference` type by existentially boxing it.

```
data SomeAsset f where SomeAsset :: Asset a => f a -> SomeAsset f

reference :: Parser (SomeAsset Reference)
reference = asum
    [ string "User" *> go UserRef
    , string "Port" *> go PortRef
    , string "Model" *> go ModelRef
    ]
    where
    go :: Asset a => (Int -> Parser (Reference a)) -> Parser (SomeAsset Reference)
    go constructor = constructor <$ char '-' <*> int

loadAndSend :: SomeAsset Reference -> IO ()
loadAndSend (SomeAsset reference) = load reference >>= traverse_ send
```

Comment: Ok, but now I have just pushed my problem from `Asset` to `Reference`? I now need to create a `Reference a` where I don't know what `a` is until I read data from the WebSocket or disk.  I think given the choice, I'd prefer to keep this problem isolated to the Asset class which, outside of the IO portion of the code, is much less common.

Comment: @JohnF.Miller You said in your question, "I can determine at run time what the concrete type of `a` is. This information is encoded in the `Reference` type.". So you just need to modify `Reference` to carry this information in a way the compiler can see. Of course I can't give advice on how to do that completely blind -- you'll have to include details about *how* `Reference` carries this information to get anything more targeted than what I've written so far. edit: I see that you've edited the question to include some of this now. I'll update my answer to discuss this.

Comment: @JohnF.Miller I've included some further details that model your updated information.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the answers from [Daniel Wagner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51832110/163177) and [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51832855/163177), I ultimately resolved my issue using a combination of the two which I place here in hopes it will aid others.

First, per Daniel Wagner's answer, I added a phantom type to `Reference`:

```
data Reference a = Ref {
    assetType:: String
  , assetIndex :: Int
  } deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Generic)
```

I chose not to use a GADT constructors and leave the string reference to `assetType` as I frequently send references over the wire and/or parse them from incoming text. I felt there were too many code points where I needed a generic reference. For those cases, I fill in the phantom type with `Void`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}
data Void
-- make this reference Generic
voidRef :: Reference a -> Reference Void
castRef :: a -> Reference b -> Reference a
--        ^^^ Note this can be undefined used only for its type
```

With this the `load` type signature becomes `load :: Asset a => Reference a -> IO (Maybe  a)`  So the Asset is always matches the type of the Reference.  (Yay type safety!)

That still doesn't address how to load a generic reference.  For those cases, I wrote some new code using the second half of Ben's answer.  By wrapping the asset in `SomeAsset`, I can return a Type which is making the type checker happy.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Data.Aeson (encode)

loadGenericAsset :: Reference Void -> IO SomeAsset
loadGenericAsset ref =
  case assetType ref of
    "User" -> Some <$> load (castRef (undefined :: User) ref)
    "Port" -> Some <$> load (castRef (undefined :: Port) ref)
     [etc...]

send :: SomeAsset -> IO ()
send (Some a) = writeToUser (encode a)

data SomeAsset where 
  Some :: Asset a => a -> SomeAsset
```